# DOM not loading when page is fetched through CURL request

Tags: php, curl, dom

I have been using the CURL request in PHP to fetch pages. It was doing fine but when I fetch a page with so much data in it, that takes a lot of time to load the DOM the response of the CURL request shows the empty DOM.

Is there a way to add some pause or delay to get the page content i.e. DOM after the page loads successfully?

I tried to add the "sleep" after curl execute the URL for like 5 minutes but no use.

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$link);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($curl);
        if ($link == "https://dev.finduslocal.com/sitemap-state/ca.xml") {
            var_dump('Sleeping for 5 mins');
            sleep(300);
        };



        $HTTP_CODE = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);

        $dom = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html( $curl_scraped_page );

        if ($dom) {
          // my code
        } else {
           echo "DOM not found";
        }
```

Comment: If you print the `$curl_scraped_page` variable before parse the HTML, the HTML is complete?

Comment: why don't you use file_get_contents

Comment: @fonini No, that's the problem. The page content is not loaded before.

Comment: @ZeeshanFaiz Did you try to increase the request timeout?

Comment: Adding some `sleep` time here is likely not going to fix whatever issues you are having. There is nothing asynchronous going on here, things happen one after the other - so “sleeping” anywhere in between is not going to fix anything.

Comment: @fonini The request timeout is not the problem because the page is loading after some time. It's just taking a bit more time than usual.

Comment: @ZeeshanFaiz The response is chunked? See some code here: https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/issues/369

Comment: If the page is taking time to load, that curl call will not return until it's finished or it times out. Putting a delay after it will make no difference.